# ¿Cómo ejecutar una consulta SQL al iniciar una aplicación web de Net Core y guardarlo en una variable de sesión?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estoy creando una aplicación web en Net core, y necesito cargar unos datos de la base de datos al iniciar la aplicación, lanzando una consulta de forma asíncrona, de forma que paralelamente a la consulta que tardará en ejecutarse, siga cargando el aplicativo. Tras finalizar la consulta, necesitaría guardar estos datos en una variable accesible en todo momento, imagino que lo mejor es desde una variable de sesión.

Para ejecutar la consulta he pensado ejecutarla en el "program.cs" de forma asíncrona, y el resultado estoy intentando guardarlo en la variable de sesión que según tengo entendido por lo que he leído en la documentación de Microsoft dependiendo de si estamos en un controlador, una página de Razor o una clase nuestra, hemos de acceder mediante HttpContext para los dos primeros casos, y mediante IHttpContextAccessor desde una clase nuestra. He implementado toda la configuración en el startup.cs para soportar el uso de IHttpContextAccesor pero no consigo instanciar mi clase donde le inyecto la dependencia de IHttpContextAccesor, y por tanto no consigo probarlo, y no se si puedo o no crear mi variable de sesión con el resultado de la consulta, ni si es accesible desde páginas razor.

En definitiva,:

- ¿Dónde debería realizar mi llamada a la consulta SQL?
- ¿Debo usar variables de sesión?
- ¿Cómo debo hacer uso de estas variables para escribir/leer en ellas?

Estoy un poco confundido con tanta documentación que he leído.

Muchas gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar.

Agrego el código que estoy usando hasta el momento:

Fichero startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services
                .AddRazorPages()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
            //Soporte variables de session
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan; //TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = "AsesoramientoBP.session";
            }
                );

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddTransient<AlmacenamientoDatos>();
            //services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            //Fin soporte variables de session
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                //Soporte variables de session
                app.UseHsts();
                //Fin variables de session
            }

            //Soporte variables de session
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //Fin soporte variables de session


            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            //Soporte variables de session DUDA
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //Fin soporte variables de session

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //Soporte variables de session
            app.UseSession();
            //Fin soporte variables de session

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

Clase con la que implemento la inyección para acceder a IHttpContextAccessor:

````
public class AlmacenamientoDatos
    {

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AlmacenamientoDatos(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void SetValue ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guradado");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionClientes", "Probando!");
        }

        public string getValue ()
        {
            var valor = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionClientes");
            return valor;
        }


        public IEnumerable<ClientData> ObtenerDatosDeClientes()
        {

            IEnumerable<ClientData> ClientsData = new[]
        {
            new ClientData
            {
IdClient = 1,
Name = "pepe",
LastName = "Pérez Hervás",
DNI = "12312312Q"
            },
            new ClientData
            {
IdClient = 2,
Name = "Carlos",
LastName = "Rato Mendoza",
DNI = "23434323F"
            },
            new ClientData
            {
IdClient = 3,
Name = "Sofía",
LastName = "García Solera",
DNI = "45345434J"
            }
        };

            return ClientsData;
        }
}
```


La clase ClientData es una clase sencilla de prueba donde hay 4 propiedades de tipo string, Identificación, nombre, Dirección y Favorito.

Por otro lado, en la clase donde quiero ejecutar la consulta y guardarla en AlmacenemientoDatos es Program.cs donde simplemente para probar estoy instaciando AlmacenemientoDatos de forma normal y no consigo que funcione el valor que guardo al usar el método setValue ya que al intentar recuperarlo con getValue no devuelve nada.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos.
````

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que tienes hasta ahora, para poderte ayudar...

Comment: Una vez que arranca tu programa, tene en cuenta que no hay sesion todavia... Y cuando un usuario se conecta, no pasa por ahi.. porque ese codigo ya se ejecuto para inicializar la pagina.. que es lo que queres hacer exactamente? porque querrias guardar algo ahi?

Comment: ¿Cuando arranca la aplicación el primer programa que se ejecuta no es el program.cs? Lo que necesito hacer es según el usuario que se conecte, descargar una relación de clientes asociados a este usuario que acaba de conectar para posteriormente trabajar con estos. Por ello pensaba que al iniciar sesión, lanzar la consulta de forma asíncrona seguir con la carga del aplicativo, y el resultado de la consulta guardarlo en una variable de sesión exclusiva para este usuario. Muchas gracias por tu interés.